# How to Change Text in Popup message if color not select before add to cart

Tags: localisation

How can I change the text in the attached image?

[image]

Comment: Do you happen to be using an extension or not? Where does this happen? On a configurable product? Please give us more details on what you want to achieve and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Not using any additional plugin. This messages appears when Select Configurable Product and Click on Add to Cart without Selecting any Color or any attrib.

Comment: It is probably hardcoded in a js file. Try looking into configurable.js under the js folder

Comment: Sir. Got any Solution ?

Answer (score 2):

If the text is added as a translatable string you can change it easily by searching for it. Via FTP go to `app/locale/[your language]/` and check the CSV files for the string.

I would check with the `Mage_Catalog.csv` file. It should look something like `"Please, select item","Please, select item"`. Translate the second string.

If it's not there go to your design template `app/design/frontend/[package]/[template]/locale/[language]/translate.csv` and add the string

Comment: Dear Sander, Still unable to get Solution.